# show child checkboxes under parent checkboxes in view page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am showing check boxes in view page and data will come from the database. Here is my code and the problem is that while looping if the same parent name came it shows same parent checkboxes two times.

```
<% @permission.each do |f| %>
        <% if @controller_code != f.controller_code %>
            <% @controller_code = f.controller_code %>
            <%= check_box_tag "cntrl_#{f.controller_code}", f.controller_code, false,  :class => "Par_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Par_#{f.controller_code}" %> <%= f.controller_name %>
            <br/>
            <% @permission.each do |f| %>
                <% if @controller_code == f.controller_code %>
                    &nbsp;  &nbsp;<%= check_box_tag "action_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}",f.action_code, false,  :class => "Child_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Child_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}" %> <%= f.action_name %>
                    <br/>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>   
        <% end %>
```

> I have also tried this way but its not working properly..

```
<% @permission.each do |f| %>   
            <% if @controller_code != f.controller_code %>
            <% @controller_code = f.controller_code %>
                <%= check_box_tag "cntrl_#{f.controller_code}", f.controller_code, false,  :class => "Par_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Par_#{f.controller_code}" %> <%= f.controller_name %>
             <br/>
            <% end %>
            &nbsp;  &nbsp;<%= check_box_tag "action_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}",f.action_code, false,  :class => "Child_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Child_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}" %> <%= f.action_name %>
            <br/>        
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you trying do here? why there are two iteration over the `@permission`???

Comment: these all data will come from permission table and in that same controller code will appear in more than 1 records and all actions of same controller_code i want to show them in the child check boxes so what should i do..?

Comment: seems weird, your problem is not "is that while looping if the same parent name..". can you explain what task are you solving in general?

Comment: i have a table with fields controller_code, action_code, controller_name, action_name. And in view page i want to show the check boxes like controller_code is a parent check box and action_name will be child check box

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that i m giving exact answer for your question, i think this can help you,

```
<% @permission.each do |f| %>
    <% if @controller_code != f.controller_code %>
        <% @controller_code = f.controller_code %>
        <%= check_box_tag "cntrl_#{f.controller_code}", f.controller_code, false,  :class => "Par_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Par_#{f.controller_code}" %> <%= f.controller_name %>
    <% else %>
      <%= check_box_tag "action_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}",f.action_code, false,  :class => "Child_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Child_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}" %>        
      <%= f.action_name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution of my question here it is in controller do following

```
 @permission=Permission.all.where(active: 1)
if @permission.blank? == false
  @permissions =  Permission.all.where(active: 1).order_by(:controller_code => "asc")
else
  @permissions = ""
end
```

> And in view page do following

```
<% @permissions.each do |f| %>
        <% if @controller_code != f.controller_code %>
            <% @controller_code = f.controller_code %>
            <%= check_box_tag "cntrl_#{f.controller_code}", f.controller_code, false,  :class => "Par_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Par_#{f.controller_code}" %> <%= f.controller_name %>
            <br/>
            <% @permissions.each do |f| %>
                <% if @controller_code == f.controller_code %>
                    &nbsp;  &nbsp;<%= check_box_tag "action_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}",f.action_code, false,  :class => "Child_#{f.controller_code}", :id => "Child_#{f.controller_code}_#{f.action_code}" %> <%= f.action_name %>
                    <br/>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>   
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```